# recyclerview for chat app doesn't show any data or views

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, chat, retrofit2

Hi I'm building chat app UI with android but it runs without showing any data or views, 
I interact with a bot server that should return text after I send a text. I'm using retrofit for http connections.

the model class showing are the response from json

please help me and ask me any details you want

My adapter

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;
private List<Messages> data;
private Context mContext;

// constructor
public MessageListAdapter(List<Messages> data, Context mContext) {
    this.data = data;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView;

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {


        return new SentMessageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_message, parent, false));
    } else {


        return new RecvdMessageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bot_message, parent, false));
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    Messages messages = data.get(position);


    if (type == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {


        SentMessageHolder sentMessageHolder = (SentMessageHolder) holder;
        sentMessageHolder.messageBody.setText(messages.getText());

    } else {


        RecvdMessageHolder recvdMessageHolder = (RecvdMessageHolder) holder;
        recvdMessageHolder.messageBody.setText(messages.getText());
    }
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    Messages messages = data.get(position);


    if (messages.getRecipientId() == ("default")) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
    } else
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {


    if (data != null) {
        return data.size();

    } else return 0;
}

class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView messageBody;


    public SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);

    }
}

class RecvdMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView messageBody;

    public RecvdMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);

    }
}
```

My activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editText;
private RecyclerView mMessageRecycler;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter MessageListAdapter;
List<Messages> data;


//init client
Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient();
//contact with the interface
APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.my_msg);

    data = new ArrayList<>();

    mMessageRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reyclerview_message_list);
    MessageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(data , this);
   // messageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(MessageListAdapter);
    mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mMessageRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);




}

public void clickedbtn(View view) {
    fetchMessages();

}

private void fetchMessages() {


    Call<List<Messages>> res = apiService.getBotResponse(editText.getText().toString());

        res.enqueue(new Callback<List<Messages>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Messages>> call, Response<List<Messages>> response) {

                List<Messages> messages = response.body();
                data.addAll(messages);//Changed here
                MessageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//Changed here


                mMessageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);




            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Messages>> call, Throwable t) {


            }
        });
    }
```

My model class

```
public class Messages {

@SerializedName("recipient_id")
@Expose
private String recipientId;
@SerializedName("text")
@Expose
private String text;


public Messages(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getRecipientId() {
    return recipientId;
}

public void setRecipientId(String recipientId) {
    this.recipientId = recipientId;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

Comment: you are initializing MessageListAdapter  with an empty List<Message>, since you are adding `MessageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(data , this);` before data has come back from server

Comment: try adding `mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(MessageListAdapter);` inside your `onResponse`

Comment: was my comment helpful?

Comment: @HudiIlfeld still same not showing any views , I do that MessageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(data , this); suppose to pass my model from constructor. I'm newbie on recyclerview .  it may have logic error but i dont know where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **both** the instantiation of the `Adapter` **and** the `RecyclerView.setAdapter()` to the retrofit `onResponse()`: 
Like this:

```
Call<List<Messages>> res = apiService.getBotResponse(editText.getText().toString());

    res.enqueue(new Callback<List<Messages>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Messages>> call, Response<List<Messages>> response) {

            List<Messages> messages = response.body();
            //Init the Adpater here!!
            MessageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(data , this);
            //SetAdapter here!!
            mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(MessageListAdapter);
            data.addAll(messages);//Changed here

            MessageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//Changed here


            mMessageRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);




        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Messages>> call, Throwable t) {


        }
    });
```

### EDIT:

In addition to the above, your `clickedbtn()` should look like this:

```
public void clickedbtn(View view) {

    Messages msg = new Messages(editText.getText().toString());
    msg.setRecipientId("default");

    data.add(msg);
    MessageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    fetchMessages();

}
```

Comment: let me know if it's helpful :)

Comment: I try to remove context from constructor
    public MessageListAdapter(List<Messages> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
and did your answer, The issue now is it worked only for the received message it show view for the received message but user message not shown up as a view

Comment: why are u removing context?

Comment: bc  MessageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(data , this); didnt work and asks me to change type of context to callback retrofit type I tried it but the app crashs when i lunch it so i remove it

Comment: No. you should type as following `MessageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(data , MainActivity.this);` since you are refering to a class member from anonymous class [i.e callback], `this` keyword only is refering to the inner class, therefore you need to add **MainActivity.this** in order for Java to understand to which context you refering

Comment: add it back no errors but same result it show only server message view layout and not my msg from edit text label. I want to both views be represented on the recycle as chat message

Comment: my json response from server is "recipient_id": "default",
"text": "Hey there!!" that's why my if contain equals to default to return some layout else do the second

Comment: Do you have a link to your project so i can see it from inside?

Comment: I just make a repo check it https://github.com/Noarah/botPress/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/noarah/botPress

Comment: if you want to try the code please tell me so i can open the ngrok tunnel

Comment: you got any thoughts ? maybe i need to pass the keys of views in my model or make a new list of the text i sent vie editText field. !

Comment: I am gonna check it out now :)

Comment: I cannot open your github repo in android studio

Comment: you are missing the **app** directory in your github repo. are you pushing to your origin from within the android studio?

Comment: I just make the share via abdroid studio you can now check it https://github.com/Noarah/botPress feel free to check any time i'll wait

Comment: do you have email so i can get in touch with you more easily?

Comment: absolutely nr.khalfallah@gmail.com